# Asp net core publish on azure app services 500 server error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to publish my existing asp net core 2.0 web application to azure app services. My app is working in debug on my computer. I followed this tutorial [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase . Everything went smooth without errors. But when I go to the webpage I just get a very helpful 500 error. What can I do? How to debug? Im new to azure.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a way to remotely view the exception in order to get more information for debugging. Here is a helpful doc on setting up Remote Debugging.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure

Check out the section "Remote Debug ASP.NET Core on an Azure App Service"

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now

Comment: My Sql connection string was wrong so that was causing the error.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!